# Swift UIGestureEvent Crashes Without @objc Added Next To Selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I had a very weird bug and while I found a solution I am very curious as to what is going on and why my fix worked. I am using Swift.

Here is the situation

I created a class, clickableImage, which has a touchCallback member variable. Inside of clickableImage is this:

```
var touchCallback:((K_PreviewImage)->Void)
    {
        set{
            if(_touchCallback == nil)
            {
                var tap:UIGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:"tapped:")
                _image.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
            }

            _touchCallback = newValue
        }
        get{
            return _touchCallback
        }
    }

    func tapped(tap:UITapGestureRecognizer)
    {
        println("Here")
        if(_touchCallback != nil)
        {
            touchCallback(self)
        }
    }
```

If I have a ViewController class and do this

```
var k:clickableImage!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        k = k:clickableImage("image.png")
        k.touchCallback = nestedTap
        view.addSubview(k.view)
    }

    func nestedTap(k:K_PreviewImage)
    {
        println("Successs")
    }
```

If I touch the image, I get a crash, with just a generic bad memory access issue. When I turned on zombies I sometimes got a weird "message sent to deallocted object".

However when I changed the clickableImage event listener to

```
  @objc func tapped(tap:UITapGestureRecognizer)
    {
        println("Here")
        if(_touchCallback != nil)
        {
            touchCallback(self)
        }
    }
```

The problem fixed itself. It no longer thinks the message is going to a 'deallocated' object.

My question is what is going on here? Why is it crashing without the @objc? Because there are many times when I add touch events and I DONT need to add this @objc. Why does this situation 'arbitrarily' require it?

Comment: "message sent to deallocted object" with zombies is not "weird". It is what zombies are _for_.

Comment: Does your `clickableImage` class inherit from NSObject?

Comment: No it doesn't inherit from NSObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to retain a reference to the object.

If you have complex object:
ObjectA.

And it has a view
ObjectA.view

And you add that view to another view

```
addSubview(ObjectA.view)
```

If you don't keep a reference to ObjectA, then ObjectA will get destroyed, but the ObjectA.view object will remain and then it will try to contact its parent, ObjectA which is now nil. By creating an array to keep track of the objects, ObjectA is retained.